# Can I style Google Desktop wigdets with CSS or some other technology?

Tags: javascript, css

I just started to develop a widget for Google desktop and found the platform quite limited. From what I could see, the widgets are using XML to define the interface that is a mix of HTML with some built-in user controls.

Can I use a CSS style attached to it so I can define the styles I want for components? Or at least define styles in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, CSS is the easiest way to style widget components.
Decent documentation here: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/DevGuideStyleSheets